# Delete Laste (Blank) Line of Row

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I've started a new job, and my boss wants me to fix up their reports which are pulled from Sharepoint to Excel (in .iqy format), and come across as an absolute mess in some areas.

The main issue that several columns are numeric scores, individuals names, dates, etc while a few are longer text inputs for 3-7 sentences (often bullet pointed). These longer text cells for some reason can have anywhere from 0 to 5 blank lines at the start of the cell, as well as the end, which looks extremely messy and can prove very time consuming for members of the team who struggle with Excel to manually delete.

I found a VBA script that has deleted all of the lines at the START of these cells, but cannot figure out how to also apply it to the blank lines at the END of these cells... if anyone could help out it would be massive appreciated!

Code for the start of the cells that is working is as follows:

```
Sub RemoveFirstLine(ByRef Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range
    For Each xCell In Target.Cells
        xCell.Value = Right(xCell.Value, Len(xCell.Value) - InStr(1, xCell.Value, vbLf))
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub StartRemove()
Dim xRng As Range
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Excel 10 Tutorial", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
   If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   On Error Resume Next
   RemoveFirstLine xRng
End Sub
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated, I'm only so-so with this stuff and Google is coming up completely blank for me on this issue with everything focusing on deleting blank rows and not blank lines within them!

Answer (score 0):

This will strip all leading and trailing `vbLf` characters

```vb
Sub RemoveLineFeeds(ByRef Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Txt As String
    For Each xCell In Target.Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(xCell.Value2) And Not IsEmpty(xCell) Then
            Txt = xCell.Value2
            i = 1
            Do While Mid$(Txt, i, 1) = vbLf
                i  = i + 1
            Loop
            If i > 1 Then
                Txt = Mid$(Txt, i)
            End If

            i = Len(Txt)
            Do While Mid$(Txt, i, 1) = vbLf
                i  = i - 1
            Loop
            If i < Len(Txt) Then
                Txt = Left$(Txt, i)
            End If
            
            xCell.Value2 = Txt
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me with this, hugely appreciated. For some reason though, it isn't being recognised at all when I go to run it - the option just isn't there?

Comment: Where did you put the code? It should be in a standard module.  And when you "when I go to run it" what exactly do you do?